# Google Map API with Listing AJAX based

Tags: php, ajax, google-maps-api-2

Please see this reference site.

http://www.kw.com/kw/propertysearch.html

In this site you can see a special thing in map. If you drag drop, Zoom a map to particular pointer then the listing (at the bottom) is automatically refreshed on the basis on AJAX.

I want same thing in my website, I have already used google map API, But in this manner I never used. 
Please suggest me some plugins, API by using which I can achieve this.

Thanks
Ash

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use Ajax for this (although it might be better for large marker collections).

See, markers, as any JS object, can hold unlimited properties. For example, if you declare a marker as

```
var newmarker=new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(-80,40), 
        map: map
});
```

You can later add properties such as

```
newmarker.myattributes= { 
     type: 'Land/Lot',
     photos:20,
     address: '4710 Cedar Hill Ln Black Earth, WI'
     price: '$1,199,000'
     beds: 4,
     baths: 2,
     sqft: 4000
};
```

Then, if you have an onlick listener, you can access those properties:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(newmarker, 'click', function() {
    var newdiv=jQuery('<div id="property"></div>');
    newdiv.append('type :'+newmarker.myattributes.type);
    newdiv.append('photos :'+newmarker.myattributes.photos);
    newdiv.append('address :'+newmarker.myattributes.address);
    ...

    newdiv.appendTo('#container');
});
```

In this example I used a new div, but you can insert the marker fields in the native [InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#InfoWindow) object too.